# How to call api endpoint with AWS Congito in C#

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-cognito

We have a system written in c#(.net framework 4.7) which calls a restful API endpoint periodically to get information. Our vendor, who built the API originally, changed the authentication mechanism. Now the system starts to use AWS Congito to save the user information. In order for my C# code to call the API, we need to add an authorization header for each request.

I have no experience with AWS at all. My questions are:

1. How can I generate an ID token to attach to the header?
2. I have the user pool id, client id, username, and password now. Do I need any other information?
3. I found some NuGet packages that might be helpful such as AWSSDK, AWSSDK.Core, AWSSDK.CognitoIdentityProvider, etc. But I am not sure whether they support .net framework. In addition, I have no clue how to use them. Where can I find some sample code?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you don't generate the ID token. You will get it as a response from AWS Cognito upon successful authentication and/or providing correct refresh token.

First, you need to authenticate your user. This is done using the [InitiateAuth](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/items/CognitoIdentityProvider/MICognitoIdentityProviderInitiateAuthInitiateAuthRequest.html) API of Cognito. There, you need to provide the `AuthFlow`: `USER_PASSWORD_AUTH`, `AuthParameters` with two keys: `USERNAME` and `PASSWORD` and `ClientId`. In response you should get the ID token.

Now that you have the token, you can send it as you prefer.

See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/items/CognitoIdentityProvider/TInitiateAuthRequest.html for more details.